# Response.OutputStream.Write write completely on disconnected client

Tags: asp.net

Here is my code, let me explain with code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCount && Response.IsClientConnected; i++)
        {                

            buffer = _BinaryReader.ReadBytes(readLen);
            Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            LockAndUpdateTraffic(FileID, buffer.Length);

        }
```

first I check whether client is connected or not but alwayes IsClientConnected return true even if client is disconnected
my Response.OutputStream.Write is completely done an no exception occure
when I am debugging on visual studio 2008 everything is ok
but when I run my application on IIS hosted on windows 2008 R2 this problem occured

I Need to measure how many byte I sent to client but with this problem My result is all bytes  have been sent